# Decode PostgreSQL bytea[] into base64 string using Javascript Buffer

Tags: javascript, postgresql, blob, bytea

I have the following workflow from a ReactJS frontend that in the end saves an array of `Blob` items into a Postgresql database on a column of type `bytea[]`.

The array object's value that is sent from React looks like:

```js
[
   "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7TdYUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABBPrOazmET..." ,
   "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7TdYUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABBPrOazmET..." 
]
```

In the backend, the DTO that takes this value to further save into the database within the POST request looks like this:

```js
export interface IItem extends IInteractable {
  possibleTextAnswers?: string[];
  possibleMediaAnswers?: Blob[];
}
```

Where the `possibleMediaAnswers` is the column that will save the array of `Blob` items.

Then, when I fetch the `Item` on the frontend, the object is fetched through the same DTO, and it has the value when fetched in React:

`[ {type: 'Buffer', data: Array(215499)}, {type: 'Buffer', data: Array(215499)} ]`

How can I decode this and get to the same values as in the beginning?

What I've tried so far:

```js
const decodedImageSources = record.possibleMediaAnswers.map((choice) => {
      const base64String = Buffer.from(choice.data).toString('base64');
      return base64String;
})
```

When I check the console for the value of the `base64String` this is equal to:
`RSdceDY0NjE3NDYxM2E2OTZkNjE2NzY1MmY2YTcw...`

I would expect the decoded string to also contain the `data:image/jpeg;base64,`  part, but it doesn't.

I also tried the way: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64String}`, but the image still doesn't appear.

I assume the problem comes from here: `Buffer.from(choice.data).toString('base64')`?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A `Blob` does (or can) contain a mime type, a `bytea` does not - you'll need to store that separately. You may want to consider using a separate `table blobs(itemid int, type text check ismimetype(type), content bytea)` instead of using an array in the `items` table

Comment: That was my backup implementation idea, I thought there was a possibility of decoding the `bytea[]` elements this way

Comment: No - unless you know they're *always* `image/jpeg` blobs

Comment: `Buffer.from(choice.data)` looks weird. The response you got originally (`{type: 'Buffer', data: Array(215499)}`) makes it look like `choice` is a buffer already - you should then need only `const base64String = choice.toString('base64');`. But please show more of your code, it's not really clear where `record` comes from and what database library you are using to query from postgres that would convert the `bytea` items to buffers - and the other way round, how you are parsing the values sent by the client and storing them into the database (which might also be causing the issue)